# How to filter date array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, date, filter

How to filter below date array.i need to get every five min data from this array.Means if my first index data is "2021-01-06 10:52:15 +0000" than I need second data from array after five minutes is "2021-01-06 10:57:15 +0000".This way i need every five minutes date data from below array.

```
[2021-01-06 10:52:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:52:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:52:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:53:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:53:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:53:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:53:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:54:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:54:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:54:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:54:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:55:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:55:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:55:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:55:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:56:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:56:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:56:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:56:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:57:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:57:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:57:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:57:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:58:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:58:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:58:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:58:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:59:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:59:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:59:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:59:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:00:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:00:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:00:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:00:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:01:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:01:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:01:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:01:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:02:00 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:02:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:02:30 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:02:45 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:05:00 +0000]
```

This is a just one part of array.In my case array is increasing every 15 seconds so the date data amount is very high getting from the server.

In above array if filter record is not available then need to add next record from array.for example if "2021-01-06 10:57:15 +0000" date and time is not available in the array than need to add "2021-01-06 10:57:30 +0000" or 2021-01-06 11:02:15 +0000.

Comment: This question looks narrowly scoped, and clear. It appears to be answerable, so I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a variable to store the difference in minutes. Get the first date as reference and create a collection with it. Then filter the rest of the dates checking if the minute component between the the reference date and the current date are equal to the difference. If true increase the difference and return true otherwise just return false. Add the result of the filter to the collection of a single date:

Try like this:

```
var diff = 5
if let reference = dates.first {
    let filtered = [reference] + dates.dropFirst().filter({
        if Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: reference, to: $0).minute! == diff {
            diff += 5
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
    print(filtered)  // [2021-01-06 10:52:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 10:57:15 +0000, 2021-01-06 11:02:15 +0000]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo for the answer. is it possible if this data "2021-01-06 10:57:15 +0000"  is not in data array than how we can get next record. because ones filter sequens is break remaining data also not filtered.

Comment: @skyline you would need to provide more details in your post (your code). The logic would be pretty much the same but instead of returning true or false you would be appending the dates to your filtered result.

Comment: Sure @LeoDabus. I have edited my question.some time some hours of data is not coming in the array so at that time next data is not filtering and filter is stop from last data.At that time if that particular data is missing in the array next data should add or filter is going on and next value will add.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to iterate over the array.

Store the initial date in a new array.

Then iterate through the array and compare the time difference of the current iterated date element with the last one stored in the new array.

If it is at least 5 minutes, store it in the new array and go on.

Comment: Thanks @volker for your feed back.This is a just one part of array.In my case array is increasing every 15 seconds so the date data amount is very high.Is there any filter can apply to get data.

Comment: so just check when retrieving data each 15 seconds if 5 minutes are over and only store the value then